# problemas de URLs duplicada

Tags: url, seo

hola comunidad estoy trabjando en lo que es el **SEO** y tengo una pagina de noticias la cual uso para practicar todo los dias las tecnicas para pocicionamiento en google , resulta que [mi pagina de noticias](http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com) se me estan duplicando las URLs y no entiendo por que, es decir si yo tengo una noticia estructurada de la siguiente manera....   **ejemplo**

```
http://example.com/noticia/4/murio-el-gato
```

esta es una URL que te llevaria a esa noticia de que murio el gato

pero google tambien me esta indexando esa URL de la siguiente manera

```
http://example.com/noticia/4/
```

esto llevaria a la misma noticia y no es algo bueno por que se esta duplicando el contenido, he hecho lo de las URLs canonicas para mi URL orginal `http://example.com/noticia/4/murio-el-gato`  de la manera que indica google

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://example.com/noticia/4/murio-el-gato">
```

pero aun asi cada vez que publico una noticia en mi web se duplica el contenido como lo explique mas arriba alguien me puede echar una mano con esto por favor ?

Comment: Un ejemplo concreto de alguna página que veas duplicada ? Cierra el elemento link <.../>

Answer (score 1):

Definir la url canonica debe ser suficiente para evitar se indexen otras url con contenido duplicado.

```
  <link rel="canonical" href="http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/noticias-internacionales/43/Donald-Duck-Tenemos-una-crisis" />
```

> pero aun asi cada vez que publico una noticia en mi web se duplica el
>   contenido como lo explique mas arriba alguien me puede echar una mano
>   con esto por favor ?

Lo único que podría causar esto es que

-Tuvieras versiones de páginas que no tuvieran definido el enlace canonico correcto.

Te sugiero revisar

-Cerrar el elemento link:

```
 <link rel="canonical" href="http://......." />
```

-Usar el url absoluto, definiendo el protocolo `https://`, ejemplo:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/noticias-internacionales/43/Donald-Duck-Tenemos-una-crisis" />
```

Comment: entonces en vez de `http` poner la URL canonica como `https`  y cerrar la el elemento link con eso bastaria?

Comment: en realidad veo que la mayoría de tus url son http:// , me refería a que si no agregas la liga absoluta el link canonico no funcionaría, tienes un ejemplo el cual veas repetido? @andygibbs

Comment: pues hasta ahora mi sitio esta en web console de google estos son los tres links que tengo en `google search console`  `http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/ `, `https://mirandaenloscomentarios.com/`, `http://www.mirandaenloscomentarios.com/`  a que te refieres con `si no agregas la liga absoluta el link canonico no funcionaría`

Comment: el normal que uso es `http://mirandaenloscomentarios.com`  no uso ` https` por que aun no he comprado los sertificados